# Analyze by day within Date Range

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to find a daily average population within a date range.
I have everyone declared "active" or not based on their in and out date against my date range.
This is my "active" formula:

(({View_People.BookingDateTime} <= {?pf_StartDate} and {@ff_FinalReleaseNull} >= {?pf_EndDate})
or
({View_People.BookingDateTime} <= {?pf_StartDate} and {@ff_FinalReleaseNull} >= {?pf_StartDate} and {@ff_FinalReleaseNull} <= {?pf_EndDate})
or
({View_People.BookingDateTime}} >= {?pf_StartDate} and {@ff_FinalReleaseNull} <= {?pf_EndDate})

OR {@ff_FinalReleaseNull} = currentdate)
and
{@ff_FinalReleaseNull} <= currentdate

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get this to break down daily within the date range I gave it as I am not comparing to a specific field, I just need to know how many are active each day within that range.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried a date range parameter, tried datepart, tried a crosstab (though I am not an expert at those).